# restarting one stage in jenkins pipeline wiping out existing directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, restart, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using jenkins declarative pipeline jenkinsfile for our project. we want to try the option restart at stage.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'worker' }

  stages {
    stage('clean directory') {
      steps {
        cleanWs()
      }
    }
    stage('checkout') {
      steps {
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'develop']], extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: devops], [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxx', url: git@github.com/test/devops.git]]])
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'develop']], extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: harness], [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxx', url: git@github.com/test/harness.git]]])
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'develop']], extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: automation], [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxx', url: git@github.com/test/automation.git]]])
      }
    }
    stage('build initial commit to release train') {
      steps {
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
export TASK="build_initial_commit"
            cd automation
            sh main.sh
          '''
      }
    }
    stage('deploy application') {
      steps {
        sh '''#!/bin/bashexport TASK="deploy"
            cd automation
            sh main.sh
          '''
      }
    }
    }
    }
```

and in jenkins I am using 'Pipeline script from SCM'. Jenkinsfile is present in automation.git repo (which is also defined in checkout stage)

Whenever I am restarting stage from GUI from 3rd one .. the workspace directory automatically gets cleaned up and it checksout automation.git ..
and the run fails as the other cloned repos were got cleaned...

how to handle this.. I want to restart the stage without wiping out the workspace dir..
if we just want to run the 3rd step 'deploy application' ..
I am not able to do , as the step depends on all 3 repos.. and
while restarting only 3rd stage the workspace is getting wiped out.. and as checkout is done in 1st stage(skipped) ... job is failing

how do I run only 3rd stage with retaining the old workspace ..

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SHOULD_CLEAN = true

pipeline {
  agent { label 'worker' }

  stages {
    stage('clean directory') {
      steps {
        script {
          if (SHOULD_CLEAN) {
            cleanWs()
            SHOULD_CLEAN = false
          } else {
            echo 'Skipping workspace clean'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```